# Creating custom Alpine Linux ISO with an answer file built-in

Tags: iso, alpine-linux

I couldn't find any guide or documentation referring on how to add files to a custom Alpine Linux ISO, the nearest i could find is [this](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage) page on the Alpine Wiki about creating a custom ISO image with `mkimage`

I would prefer to have my automated installation scripts and answer files directly on the ISO instead of having to download them through `wget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for examples on [Alpine Linux repositories](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/) and carefully reading the [APKBUILD reference](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/APKBUILD_Reference) on the Alpine's official wiki, i've managed to create my own `APKBUILD` that simply copies two static files to `/usr/bin`

```bsh
# Maintainer: henriquehbr <henriqueborgeshbr@gmail.com>
pkgname=alpine.sh
pkgver=0.1.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="An answerfile and automated post-install script for Alpine Linux"
url="https://git.sr.ht/~henriquehbr/alpine.sh"
arch="all"
license="GPL-3.0-or-later"
source="answerfile post-install"
options="!check"

package() {
    installation_path="$pkgdir"/usr/bin
    mkdir -p "$installation_path"
    cp -f post-install "$installation_path"
    cp -f answerfile "$installation_path"
    chmod 755 "$installation_path"/post-install
}
```

> Both the `answerfile` and `post-install` script are on the same directory of the `APKBUILD`

In order to build an `.apk` for it, it's required to generate the checksums by running:

```
abuild checksum
```

And then build it with:

```
abuild -r
```

An `.apk` file of your package will be created at `$HOME/packages/$USER/x86_64/$pkgname-$pkgver.apk`, this path might vary depending on your settings/system, and also, i used the `x86_64` architecture here as an example

Answer (score 0):

Make a package containing your files and add it, like any other package in that instruction, to your image, by adding it to the `apks` list in your profile script.

(In the end, you're building an alpine-derived distro here. So you should use the distro-building tools that they have: APKs.)

Comment: I've tried understanding Alpine's wiki guides on how to create a package and the APKBUILD reference documentation, and even getting some simpler examples from their aports at gitlab, but all of them seem overkill for what i'm trying to do (which makes sense, as they are compiled applications), do you know a simple way to just package some static plain-text files and shell scripts and send them to `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: It *is* the simple way.

Comment: What do you mean by _the simple way_?

Comment: building an APK to include files in an Alpine image. It's the easy way. I don't think there's an easier way.

Comment: I know, that's what i'm trying to do, but Alpine's documentation on that is not clear enough, and the available examples that i've found are all for compiled packages, if you could point out a package that is only composed of static files which i could use as an example, that would be helpful